# Header defined, but not visible. 'm_nCmdShow' : undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have small application with dialog that shows error  `'m_nCmdShow' : undeclared identifier` during compile

`m_nCmdShow` is defined in `<afxwin.h>`. Where is aproblem?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "auth.h"

#include "Dialog.h"
#include <afxwin.h>

int userNotify ( int iNotificationType, char* pcNotificationText )
{

    Dialog dlg;
    dlg.txt= pcNotificationText;
    int r= dlg.ShowWindow (m_nCmdShow);
    //int r= dlg.DoModal();
    return r;
}
```

Comment: It is not in scope. Would like to remove comment, but can't it seems.

Comment: m_nCmdShow is only defined inside the CWinApp class. Your code shows a function that is not in the scope of CWinApp.

Answer (score 0):

Its part of CWinApp class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8ts5zskx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Use:

```
AfxGetApp()->m_nCmdShow
```

[edit]

as in ScottMcP-MVP comment, in your code you have not called CDialog::Create() method before ShowWindow. Here you will find good tutorial on modeless dialogs:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1651/Tutorial-Modeless-Dialogs-with-MFC

you still must move your `dlg` variable outside `userNotify` function, otherwise it will destory your dialog once function returns.

Comment: Now application crashes on int r= dlg.ShowWindow (AfxGetApp()->m_nCmdShow);

Comment: Probably you dont have application main window: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k9f064x.aspx. You can try using GetStartupInfo() : m_nCmdShow seems to be the same parameter as STARTUPINFO::wShowWindow which is being returned by this function.

Comment: I have added code
 Dialog dlg;
 STARTUPINFOA si;
 GetStartupInfo(&si);
 int r= dlg.ShowWindow (  si.wShowWindow); But it crashes in the same place

Comment: This should be: STARTUPINFO si={sizeof(STARTUPINFO)}; GetStartupInfo(&si);. As for the crashes, its obvious from your code why they happen, you use ShowWindow which creates modeless dialog, function userNotify shows its window, and then it finishes and calls ~Dialog, thats Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: You have not created the dialog window, so ShowWindow will assert. See my answer about creating a nonmodal dialog.